Mono-repo with turbo and esbuild combination - JSON files changes not triggering watch build
I have a typescript backend mono-repo and am using a combination of pnpm, turbo and esbuild tools. I have setup the standard watch mechanism by running the "turbo watch build" command which, in my understanding, monitors all the sub-packages files and triggers a corresponding sub-packages builds.
Triggers on the .ts files work correctly. Problem I have is that .json files are not triggering a thing.
I've been searching the net for the low-level explanations of what does the "turbo watch" use in the background and how to, and where to, properly configure what files/patterns to watch over but had no success.
Does the esbuild.config.ts dictates this, is it the turbo.json, is it the package.json, or even some combination?
I've tried all sorts of the combinations but nothing worked eventually. I'm asking for a general understanding of the turbo watch mechanism and what's the proper way to have it configured. Thanks in advance! I'll share code snippets if needed.
I had esbuild.config.ts initialy congifured like:
import { build } from "esbuild"

build({
    entryPoints: ['./src/**/*.ts'],
    platform: 'node',
    packages: 'external',
    outdir: 'dist/',
    format: 'cjs',
    sourcemap: "linked"
}).then(r => console.log('done'))

and altered it to this:
import { build } from "esbuild"

build({
    entryPoints: ['./src/**/*.ts', './src/**/*.json'],
    platform: 'node',
    packages: 'external',
    outdir: 'dist/',
    format: 'cjs',
    sourcemap: "linked",
    loader: {
        '.json': 'json'
    },
}).then(r => console.log('done'))

I've also tried with the turbo.json attribute of tasks.build.inputs.

Actually I found out what was causing problems I had here. It seems that turbo doesn't watch files that are git-ignored, which was the case for me. And although explicitly specifying the ignored file in the turbo.json's tasks.build.inputs field it didn't take any effect.
I had to specify a separate file-specific nodemon watcher which handles the ignored file and is started simultaneously with the general turbo's watch mechanism.
